# Build _msearch query in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I tried to write the **_msearch** elasticsearch query in Nodejs. But I'm getting the following error

```
{"module":"Search","type":"Success","response":{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The msearch request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The msearch request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"},"status":400}}
```

I have created the search template in elasticsearch using kibana. It's working in kibana. I have tried to add `\n` at end of the string, still getting the same error. Here is my full code.

```
    let doc=`{"index":"my_index"}
{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.sent", "value":"0" }  }
{"index":"my_index"}
{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"open" }  }
{"index":"my_index"}
{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"click" }  }
{"index":"my_index"}
{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"bounce" }  }
`;
            let reqObj = {
                uri: API_URL+INDEX+'_msearch/template',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
                body: doc,
                json: true
            };
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                request(reqObj, (err, res, body) => {
                    if(err) return reject(this.Response("Search","error",err));
                    return resolve(this.Response("Search","Success",body));
                });
            });
```

I tried to remove extra spaces still same result

```
let doc=`{"index":"my_index"}{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.sent", "value":"0" }  }{"index":"my_index"}{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"open" }  }{"index":"my_index"}{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"click" }  }{"index":"my_index"}{  "id": "count", "params": {  "domain":"'+domain+'", "condition":"attributes.status", "value":"bounce" }  }`;
```

Comment: You probably need to remove the leading spaces in your query

Comment: you mean between the curly braces?

Comment: No before the opening curly braces, there must be no spaces all the way down up to the newline

Comment: I tried to remove extra spaces still same result. see updated question and how entered the payload.thanks

Comment: No, you need to keep the newlines between each lines, but remove all spaces at the beginning of each lines. Each curly brace must be at columns 0 in your editor

Comment: I removed the indent added by the editor.same result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact content you have now?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: now you're missing the last newline after the last line, which is exactly what the error complains about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178943/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-val).

Comment: I think you should remove `json:true` as the content is not json
also the content type should be `application/x-ndjson` not `application/json`

Comment: @Val I removed `json:true`. It's working. It seems request module is parsing the payload before it's sent. Please add the answer. this might help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to remove all leading spaces before the opening curly braces and also ensure that you have a newline character after the last line.

Moreover, you probably need to remove the `json: true` and change the `application/json` content-type to `application/x-ndjson`.